# Is Research Tora's workbench affected by quality "gem XP" gained modifiers?

Tags: path-of-exile

When Tora is in the Research branch of the Syndicate, she offers a workbench that adds a flat amount of gem XP to any gem.  Does this gem XP amount change if the gem has a quality modifier that increases the amount of gem XP that gem gets, like Enhance/Empower/Enlighten Support's quality modifiers. I was under the impression that was only increased gem XP through kills, and not from a workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, such modifiers affect XP gained from Tora's workbench.

This was tested by the player base, and the results documented in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/a5u285/empowerenlightenenhances_quality_does_affect/).  To cut to the chase, here's the key before/after screenshot:

[image]

Note that the workbench normally adds 200,000,000 experience (as described in its tooltip), but after using the bench, the gem has gained 400,000,000 experience.  This is due to the gem's "This Gem gains 100% increased Experience" mod from quality.